# ¿Como puedo subir multiples images con php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que quiero hacer es subir un producto (que esto si me funciona) y las imagenes de ese producto en otra tabla distinta en este caso galeria, y luego guardar el id del producto y la imagen y almacenarlos en la tabla productos_galeria.

Mis tablas son:
**productos**
- producto_id
- producto_title
- producto_price
- producto_description
- producto_image

**galeria**
- imagen_id
- imagen_name
- imagen_date

**productos_galeria**
- imagen_id
- producto_id

**Mi codigo**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $categoria_lists = $_POST['categoria_id'];
    $producto_steps = $_POST['producto_title'];
    $producto_price = $_POST['producto_price'];
    $producto_description = $_POST['producto_description'];

    $producto_image = $_FILES['producto_image']['tmp_name'];

    $producto_image_upload = '../' . $items_config['images_folder'] . $_FILES['producto_image']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($producto_image, $producto_image_upload);

    $statment = $connect->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO productos (producto_id,producto_title,producto_price,producto_description,producto_image) VALUES (null, :producto_title, :producto_price, :producto_description, :producto_image)'
        );

   $statment->execute(array(
        ':producto_title' => $producto_title,
        ':producto_price' => $producto_price,
        ':producto_description' => $producto_description,
        ':producto_image' => $_FILES['producto_image']['name']
        ));

   $i=1;

    foreach ($_FILES['imagen_name']['name'] as $f)
        {

    $imagen_name = $_FILES['imagen_name']['tmp_name'][$i];

    $imagen_name_upload = '../' . $items_config['imagenes_folder'] . $_FILES['imagen_name']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($imagen_name, $imagen_name_upload);

$statment = $connect->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO galeria (imagen_id,imagen_name,imagen_date) VALUES (null,:imagen_name,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'
        );

        $statment->execute(array(
        ':imagen_name' => $_FILES['imagen_name']['name'][$i]
        ));


        $i++;

}

$statment = $connect->prepare("SELECT @@identity AS id");
$statment->execute();
$resultado = $statment->fetchAll();
$id = 0;
foreach ($resultado as $row) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }

$statment = $connect->prepare( 'INSERT INTO productos_galeria (imagen_id,producto_id) VALUES (:imagen_id, :producto_id)' );
$statment->bindParam(':imagen_id', $idimagen);
$statment->bindParam(':producto_id', $id);

foreach ($imagen_lists as $option_value)
{
   $idimagen = $option_value;
   $statment->execute();
}
```

Comment: Sin ceramente el problema (error que estes obteniendo) no lo veo hayas colocado. Por otro lado, yo colocaria producto_id en tabla galeria; previo a insertar en galeria) obtener el ID generado del insert en producto y entonces, usandolo insertar en galeria.

Comment: el problema es que no inserta las imagenes en la galeria  ni tampoco en productos_galeria, pero el producto se guarda correctamente

Answer (score 0):

De las tablas que mencionas yo tendria solo:

**productos** (`producto_id`, producto_title, producto_price, producto_description, producto_image)

**galeria** (imagen_id, `producto_id`, imagen_name, imagen_date)

Para tu PHP (Idea):

```
<?php
// Aqui los procesos para conectarte a tu BD (omito el IF)

   // Insertas los datos del producto
   // IMPORTANTE: Obtienes el ID del producto recien agregado
   //             aqui le llamare $producto_id (ya asignado)

  $i=0; // No se tu código o condiciones previas pero normalmente se inicia en cero; el primer elemento (salvo claro se declare/asigne de otra forma) es 0 (cero)

  foreach ($_FILES['imagen_name']['name'] as $f)
  {
     // Asumo esto ya lo tienes probado así esta correcto (no he manejado esta estructura)
     // ¿usar $_FILES es correcto para que crear $f?
     // Esto no lo he usado así solo he realizado con un archivo por vez.
     $imagen_name = $_FILES['imagen_name']['tmp_name'][$i];
     $imagen_name_upload = '../' . $items_config['imagenes_folder'] . $_FILES['imagen_name']['name'];
     move_uploaded_file($imagen_name, $imagen_name_upload);

     $statment = $connect->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO galeria (imagen_id, producto_id,imagen_name,imagen_date) VALUES (null,:prod_id,:imagen_name,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'
     );

     $statment->execute(array(
         ':prod_id' => $producto_id,
         ':imagen_name' => $_FILES['imagen_name']['name'][$i]
     ));


     $i++;

   }

// En caso consideres; los procesos para liberar la conexión de la BD (es opcional)
?>
```

A quienes revisen tu planteamiento les será de gran utilida si incluyes el error que se genera; solo saber falla hace pensar que es del lado del desarrollador o error no activado para mostrarse; mientras superas el detalle agrega (y luego quitas) `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio del Script PHP o cambia en el archivo de configuración del PHP `error_reporting` lo establezcas a `E_ALL`.

Comment: en la linea -   foreach ($_FILES['image_name']['name'] as $f) - me sale Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: una pregunta más, porque producto_id esta como prod_id ?

Comment: corregido; faltaron los ":" (dos puntos) para indicar es parámtero. Respecto al *foreach ($_FILES['image_name']['name'] as $f)* prueba con **foreach ($_FILES['image_name'] as $f)**; como ya mencione solo he trabajado con un archivo al a vez.

Comment: me guarda los datos en la base de datos pero no sube las imagenes aunque no guarda el producto_id y imagen_name me pone el nombre de una sola imagen en varias filas